# Button dynamic ng-click stuck after first click

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a button to change the status (STARTED/STOPPED). The button is created in a cell of ng-grid.

The cell is defined as `{field:'status', displayName:'Status', cellTemplate: 'cell/statusCellTemplate.html'}]` where the template is

`<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeStatus(row.getProperty('id'),'{{row.getProperty(col.field) | switchStatus}}')">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</button>`

```js
myapp.filter('switchStatus', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return (input == 'STOPPED') ? 'STARTED' : 'STOPPED';
    };
});
```

In the Plunker, the initial state is STOPPED so the rendered cell is

`<button class="btn btn-primary ng-scope ng-binding" ng-click="changeStatus(row.getProperty('id'),'STARTED')">STOPPED</button>`

Then clicking the button switch the status as expected and the rendered cell is

`<button class="btn btn-primary ng-scope ng-binding" ng-click="changeStatus(row.getProperty('id'),'STOPPED')">STARTED</button>`

But clicking the button does not switch the status which is stuck to STARTED whereas the parameter is set to STOPPED.

The [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pmgd8Fx48yTIZmcn5gbK?p=preview) that reproduces the issue.

**Edit: Better example**

The first answer made it work by removing the filter but I want to keep it. So I created an example where a button is rendered and clicking the button increments the content of the data. The counter is stuck after the first click.

Init: `<button class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" ng-click="increment(1)">Increment</button>`

Click: `<button class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" ng-click="increment(2)">Increment</button>`

Click: `<button class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" ng-click="increment(2)">Increment</button>` Should be `increment(3)`.

The modified [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQ7wvsrAihXuITK7QPrX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of things that I changed to get this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ny0Wwe?p=preview) working.

**First**, in your cell template the `changeStatus` method didn't need interpolation around the current status.  So this:

```
changeStatus(row.getProperty('id'),'{{row.getProperty(col.field) | switchStatus}}')"
```

changed to this:

```
 changeStatus(row.getProperty('id'),row.getProperty(col.field))"
```

**Second**, you'll notice that I took off the filter inside the cell template.  This would have the effect of calling the `$filter` again and reversing the toggle.

**Finally**, I noticed that the toggle logic was reversed.  So I changed this:

```
$scope.changeStatus= function(id, status) {
  console.log(status);
  $scope.currentStatus = status;
  if(status == 'STOPPED') {
    $scope.myData = [{status: 'STOPPED'}];
  } else {
    $scope.myData = [{status: 'STARTED'}];
  }
  $scope.nextStatus = $filter('switchStatus')(status);
}
```

To this:

```
$scope.changeStatus= function(id, status) {
  console.log(status);
  $scope.currentStatus = status;
  if(status == 'STOPPED') {
    $scope.myData = [{status: 'STARTED'}];
  } else {
    $scope.myData = [{status: 'STOPPED'}];
  }
  $scope.nextStatus = $filter('switchStatus')(status);
}
```

All seems to be working now.  Hope this helps.

Comment: You could make this more concise by calling the filter once in the changeStatus function and using that value to set the data and nextStatus.

Comment: It's working but you removed the filter in the template. The goal of the filter is to prepare the next value to be sent to the server. I created a new Plunker with a button that just increments a variable. I have the same problem.